# translatoR. Error in fromJSON

Tags: r, rstudio, translate

I use a translator() from package translatoR.
I run the sample code from the documents and get the error.

My code:

```
translate (dataset = NULL,
          content.field = NULL,
          content.vec = 'Hi',
          google.api.key = NULL,
          microsoft.client.id = my.microsoft.client.id,
          microsoft.client.secret = my.microsoft.client.secret,
          source.lang = 'no',
          target.lang = 'de')
```

Error:

```
Error in fromJSON (postForm ("https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13",:
  an error in assessing the argument 'content' when choosing a method for function 'fromJSON': Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE):
  error: 1411809D: SSL routines: SSL_CHECK_SERVERHELLO_TLSEXT: tls invalid ecpointformat list
```

I found many of the same issues on the Internet and none of them received a reply.

What could be causing the error?
I use a standard code from the example. Maybe my problem is in the configuration Rstudio?

I am a beginner. please help me

Answer (score -1):

Document Package ‘translateR’ show it needs import: RJSONIO,RCurl,textcat,parallel,httr. I confirmed RJSONIO is the answer.